# How to show that findContours does the same thing as cvBlob does

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, blob

I have a supervisor who wants to use only cvBlob to find connected components.

How can I prove to him that findContours can do the same? I already showed him c++ and matlab codes to prove my "theory" but he is not convinced yet.

Is there any reference from OpenCV developer that findContours can find blobs indeed?

Comment: Since you proved it in concept it doesn't matter what the documentation says or does not say. The algorithm and application is important, since you are sticking with the same set of tools/libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask your supervisor exactly why he prefers to use cvBlob.

Some people have reported that cvBlob is faster than findContours, but certainly findContours has the advantage of be the standard solution and have the support of a big community (the support of cvBlob at the moment is very bad, sorry), and much more general functionality than cvBlob (which is more target specific).

When your supervisor give an answer (if he can) then you could rebate it.

I'm the developer of cvBlob, by the way.

Comment: I've already asked. Main reason is that he has successfully used it in the past. And I think that's a good reason but our program is now based on OpenCV C++ API so I didn't want to go back into C API. Yeah, I know CVBlob is generally faster but in our case, image is large and number of blob < 50. So there will be not much difference. Thanks for your answer. It's rare for someone to give an opinion against what he developed. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can probably work around it similar to the following:

- Find contours ([cv::findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours))
- Loop over contours
- Find central point for each and minimum enclosing circle
  ([cv::minEnclosingCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle))
- Draw (fill) circle of each boundary/closed contour

Here is an example of blob detection using findContours for a [hand-tracking application](http://forum.libcinder.org/topic/simple-hand-tracking-with-kinect-opencv)  (check lines 82-107 for the above) by @[andrew-berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607635/andrew-berg).

Comment: Agree, you can easily draw the contours filled using `cv::fillConvexPoly`. So you can do it both ways and compare your results. I can't think why your professor would need something more.